# Incremental build support in Biztalk 2009 and 2010 .btproj projects?

Tags: msbuild, biztalk, biztalk-2009

While chasing incremental build time improvements, I found that .btproj files and thus all other projects that depend on these are rebuilt (partly) on each incremental build. Tracking this all the way to BizTalkCommon.targets, I found that it does a 2 pass compilation of the assembly - but only the first pass respects already built artifacts, thus breaking the incremental part of the dependency chain. The offending target can be seen in BizTalkCommon.targets (line 228):

```
<!-- Delete the assembly and rerun the build process -->
<Target Name="SecondPass"
        Condition="$(SecondBuild)!=true and $(TempAssemblyOnly)!=true">

    <Delete Files="@(IntermediateAssembly)" />
    <MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFile)" Properties="SecondBuild=true"/>
</Target>
```

I realize that there's a reason for the 2 pass build, but simply cannot believe it wouldn't be possible to specify appropriate in- and outputs for the target to handle incremental builds correctly.

Does anyone know if there's a patch for the .targets file, or if there's another good reason that incremental builds aren't supported?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enable incremental compilation of MSBuild BizTalk project with a couple of very simple changes. Basically, you need to override two targets that are defined in the `BizTalkCommon.targets` file.

Those targets can be overriden in your own .btproj files and do not require modifying the original .targets file that ships with BizTalk.

**How To**

First Create you own .targets file to host your customizations, for instance `BizTalkCustom.targets` :

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\BizTalk\BizTalkC.targets" />

<!-- Rerun the build process (second pass) -->
<Target Name="SecondPass" Condition="$(SecondBuild)!=true and $(TempAssemblyOnly)!=true and @(XLang)!=''">
    <MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFile)" Properties="SecondBuild=true" />
</Target>

<!-- Compile XLang/s orchestration -->
<Target
    Name="CompileODX"
    Condition="$(SecondBuild)==true"
    Inputs="@(XLang);$(MSBuildAllProjects);$(ClrTypesAssembly)"
    Outputs="$(BuildDone)">

  <!-- Delete previously generated C# files from XLang compilation -->
  <Delete Files="@(IntermediateAssembly)" />
  <Delete Files="@(CSharpOutputFromXLang)" />

  <XLangTask XLangItems="@(XLang)"
             ProjectReferences="@(ReferencePath)"
             WarningLevel="$(WarningLevel)"
             BpelCompliance="$(BpelCompliance)"
             DefineConstants="$(DefineConstants)"
             TreatWarningsAsErrors="$(TreatWarningsAsErrors)"
             TempAssembly="$(ClrTypesAssembly)"
             OutputDirectory="$(XLangOutputPath)">
  </XLangTask>
</Target>
```

Then, replace the last `Import` statement in your .btproj file:

```
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <Import Project="$(MyCustomExtensions)\BizTalkCustom.targets" />
```

**How doe it work**

BizTalk Server projects need somehow to be compiled in two passes. The first pass compiles schemas, maps and pipelines, whereas the second pass compiles orchestrations.

You'll notice that the overriden targets are very very similar than the original ones, defined inside the `BizTalkCommon.targets file`. In fact, I made two simple changes:

1. The first change involves modifying the `SecondPass` Target and adding an extra test in the `Condition`attribute. This test is usefull to prevent the second pass from occurring if your project does not even have Orchestrations.
2. Unfortunately, if your project contains Orchestrations, the original `SecondPass` Target deletes the intermediate assemblies and then proceed to compile the Orchestrations. However, the `CompileODX` Target does not need to run if all files are already up to date. Therefore, the second change involves moving the `Delete` Task from the `SecondPass` Target to the `CompiledODX` Target.

That's all there is to it.

Comment: works with BizTalk Server 2010. Not had a chance to try it with BizTalk Server 2010 R2, though.

Comment: Tryed it, works indeed. Build times go down significantly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is something my team ran into a while back and simply backed off customizing the build files and went with the BizTalk deployment framework instead, located [here](http://biztalkdeployment.codeplex.com/).  BizTalk does lots of "funny" things from a VS level, since 2009 was the first version BizTalk didn't use an external build process.  But I'm not sure why the second pass is needed, except maybe from a designer perspective.

Comment: BizTalk deployment framework looks promising, but it still doesn't really help the build time for incremental builds as far as I can see?

Comment: It doesn't specifically solve your issue, but has some hooks you can possibly extend to get you a little closer.  BizTalk builds are kind of a black box and messing around too much will definitely results in issues.