# BizTalk 2010 project compilation using MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I am trying to use MSBuild to compile a solution with a few BizTalk 2010 projects (maps, schemas, pipelines) and a few non-BizTalk projects (console app, web app).

MSBuild gets triggered by Nant. The problem is that, everytime I run the compilation, the BizTalk projects get recompiled (and the assembly version number changes). This happens even if there are absolutely *no* changes to *any part* of the entire solution.

In other words, If I build the solution once, the assemblies get created fine. Immediately, if I build again, the non-BizTalk assemblies do not get re-created (MSBuild reports *Skipping target "CoreCompile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files*). But, the BizTalk assemblies happily get re-created. This is annoying.

Please can someone help/advise?

Answer (score 0):

BizTalk Server 2009 and 2010 .btproj project files are, indeed, MSBuild projects. As you have noticed, the way standard BizTalk targets are authored prevents incremental build of BizTalk projects.

Fortunately, MSBuild is extensible and can be customized in many ways. Please, follow [the instructions on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660541/incremental-build-support-in-biztalk-2009-btproj-projects/7901562#7901562) to to alter the standard build logic of .btproj files in order to add incremental support for your build system.